# On one question, is it best to send one edit request with different kinds of edits or one edit for each kind?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, best-practices

I expected this question to be already asked, but couldn't find it, most probably my search-fu is weak, so here it is.

As the title mentions, what is the best practice when you find a question that needs edits on different fields, for instance, a change on the title, improving the code and eliminating some unrelated tags.

One edit request per element sounds reasonable from the perspective of atomicity.

One edit request per message sounds reasonable to help the reviewer do all the work at once.

I think that one edit request per element is best since each one can be accepted or rejected, but of course that is a programmers mindset, the two problems I can see with that option are; more items to review and that it looks like you are farming points.

But in the same example I mentioned before, imagine that two of the three changes where correct and one is not, then the right action for the reviewer is to reject the changes, which would end up in one of two ways, the reviewer has to do the right edits, or leave the question with the incorrect elements. Of course the reviewer can also wait until somebody else suggest an edit and hope for it to be completely right or be just one of the three elements.

Comment: I don't mind a downvote, although, I think that showing me my mistake would help me more, plus gives me the chance to improve or correct it. Specially in meta, isn't

Answer (score 7):

In most cases, reviewers would prefer all changes to be made in one edit. Consider this rejection reason (emphasis added):

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements **addressing multiple issues in the post**.

This suggests that multiple changes *should* be made at once.

Why? One reason is that every edit will bump the question back to the front page. It's best to do this only once if you can.

Comment: I didn't considered the bumping of the question, that is a good point. About the citation you mentioned, I thought about that as fixing, for instance, typos, code and other elements in the body of the question, but no as general as covering also other elements as tags and title at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You should edit everything that is wrong the first time.

Comment: ok, so far it seems to be the preferred way. That's how I usually do, but still thought it would be good to ask/confirm.